# How to map rpi-zero hid-gadget from us to german?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w, keyboard, hid

I’ve tried to map my RPI Zero HID-Gadget in a sh file, [here is my sh file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucki1000/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Pi/test/duckpi_german_layout.sh). 
I tried to exchange a normal german keyboard by swapping kbcodes from us-keyboard to german-keyboard layout, but if it is the right attempt, i can't swap the <>|key because in german keyboard layout we have one key for <>| this, this key is between shift and y, and this key not existing on a us keyboard.

How can i add this key [into the c file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucki1000/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Pi/test/hid-gadget-test.c)?

Or is there a better way to make it working on a german keyboard, I would like to know it

Or can i get any resources that help me?

Thanks in advance.

My [duckpi_german_layout.sh](https://github.com/lucki1000/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Pi/blob/test/duckpi_german_layout.sh) file looks so:

```
elif [ "$1" == "<" ]
then
    kbcode=''
elif [ "$1" == "|" ]
then
    kbcode=''

elif [ "$1" == "," ]     #Comma
then                     #Works
    kbcode='comma'       #
```

and I don't know what i should write into kbcode='' by <, > and |. 
If i write `'kbcode='right-alt <' to output that |` I get `unknown option: <`

OS = Stretch (9)
Kernel = 4.19.50+

I don't will connect any keyboard to my rpi. I will connect my rpi to a computer and there it should write this what I write in a txt file [my project](https://github.com/lucki1000/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Pi/)

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why don't you just select the right keyboard layout from the operating system? What operating system do you use? Is it Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: [Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/globalization/keyboards/kbdgr.html) the german keyboard use same Turkish keys ... apparently

Comment: But, the Ingo answer seem to be more appropriate...

Comment: @Ingo i don't will connect any keyboard to my rpi i will connect my rpi to a computer and there it should write this what i write in a txt file [my project](https://github.com/lucki1000/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Pi/tree/test)

Comment: That is an important information that missed you to add to your question. I have added it for you.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks @Ingo , I forgot something else?

Comment: @lucki1000 I don't know, it's your question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [hak5darren](https://github.com/hak5darren/USB-Rubber-Ducky/blob/master/Encoder/resources/de.properties) de.properties file

```
KEY_NON_US_100 = 100 // 0x64

ASCII_3E = KEY_NON_US_100, MODIFIERKEY_SHIFT
// 62 >

ASCII_7C = KEY_NON_US_100, MODIFIERKEY_RIGHT_ALT 
// 124 |

ASCII_3C = KEY_NON_US_100
// 60 <
```

from [ossiozac](https://github.com/ossiozac/Raspberry-Pi-Zero-Rubber-Ducky-Duckberry-Pi/blob/master/hid-gadget-test.c) source file **NON_US_100 KEY** `0x64` **is missing**

```
{.opt = "kp-period",    .val = 0x63},
{.opt = "kp-stop",      .val = 0x63},
--- and 0x64 not existing/missing ---
{.opt = "application",  .val = 0x65},
{.opt = "power",        .val = 0x66},
```

Add in your C file :

```
{.opt = "non-us-100",       .val = 0x64},
```

Add in your bash file:

```
elif [ "$1" == "<" ]
    then
        kbcode='non-us-100'
elif [ "$1" == ">" ]
    then
        kbcode='left-shift non-us-100'
elif [ "$1" == "|" ]
    then
        kbcode='right-alt non-us-100'
```

This key seems to be confirmed by this [document](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf) on **page 56**

NOT TESTED/NOT VERIFIED (**Edit**: seems to work, but I don't know for these next commands)

Normaly you can also test a key with 'echo' :

```
# '<'
echo -ne "\0\0\x64\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0
echo -ne "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 
# '|'
echo -ne "\x40\0\x64\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 
echo -ne "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0
# '>'
echo -ne "\x2\0\x64\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0 
echo -ne "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95278/discussion-on-answer-by-ephemeral-how-to-map-rpi-zero-hid-gadget-from-us-to-germ).